# Angular does not show output

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Have tried every solution on stackoverflow but it does not solve my problem,
my output is not showing. 
The output does appear in logs and everywhere else but due to some reason angular is unable to render it.

In my real scenario i will be receiving data from a server and i have mimicked the object structure i will be getting in the 'controller.js' file

### Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head> 

        </head>

        <body>

            <div ng-app="application" ng-controller="controller">
            <ng-view>

            <h2> Todo List: </h2>

            <ul>

            <li> {{t}}</li>
            <li> {{s}}</li>

            </ul>


        </ng-view>
            </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="application.js"></script>
        <script src="controller.js"></script>
        </body>

    </html>
```

### Controller.js

```
   var app=angular.module('application', []);
   app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
        var d= [{'Task':'Say hi!','Status':'failed'}];

        $scope.t=d[0].Task;
        $scope.s=d[0].Status;

        console.log("Task",$scope.t);
        console.log("Status",$scope.s); 

});
```

### Application.js

```
var app = angular.module("application", []);
 app.run(function(){
    console.log("App running!");
 });
```

Comment: Try commenting lines `<ng-view>` and `</ng-view>`. With the current code you probably will never see the output because you are printing it inside a `ng-view` (used for rendering _partials_ in AngularJS)

Comment: Tried that as well. Still doesnt work

Comment: Check your network traffic. Are application.js and controller.js being found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="application" ng-controller="_controller">
            <h2> Todo List: </h2>
            <ul>
                <li> {{t}}</li>
                <li> {{s}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script>            
var app=angular.module('application', []);
app.controller("_controller", function($scope) {
    var d= [{'Task':'Say hi!','Status':'failed'}];

    $scope.t=d[0].Task;

    $scope.s=d[0].Status;

    console.log("Task",$scope.t);
    console.log("Status",$scope.s); 
});


app.run(function(){
    console.log("App running!");
});            
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just include libs.

Comment: You use "var app = angular.module("application", []);" two times. It is wrong. Click right button on screen and choose an "Inspect element" option in menu to see error in browser console. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in this line

```
 console.log(App running!");
```

You forgot one "

that should be

```
   console.log("App running!");
```

Solving that your code works fine.

Comment: That was by mistake while editing the code on stackoverflow, the problem is different. It still isnt working with the correct quotes.

Comment: @Rodrigo please correct the edit by adding a " in the second code block ,i forgot that while editing your post

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in console.log, missing leading quote on App running.

```js
//script.js
var app = angular.module("application", []);
app.run(function() {
  console.log("App running!");
});

app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
  var d = [{
    'Task': 'Say hi!',
    'Status': 'failed'
  }];

  $scope.t = d[0].Task;
  $scope.s = d[0].Status;

  console.log("Task", $scope.t);
  console.log("Status", $scope.s);

});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="application" ng-controller="controller">
    <ng-view>
      <h2> Todo List: </h2>
      <ul>
        <li> {{t}}</li>
        <li> {{s}}</li>
      </ul>
    </ng-view>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That was by mistake while editing the code on stackoverflow, the problem is different. It still isnt working with the correct quotes.